# Matching users who have liked each other- How to store this information

Tags: sql, arrays, matching

I want to create a database of users who can then like each other. When a user, for example user 1, likes user 2 then this should be stored. If user 2 subsequently likes user 1 then they should both be informed.  I can't quite work out how I would structure the SQL tables for this. The way I would like to implement this would be to create an array of likes for each user where the users they like are stored. So if user 1 liked user 2,3,4 and 5 this is then stored in user 1s like array. If user 1 is then liked by user 2 then user 1s like array would be checked for user 2.

As far as I know arrays aren't available in SQL, so what would be the simplest alternative to this?

Comment: Is it over simplifying it to say you're just trying to set up a many-to-many with your `Users`?

Comment: @Dan no, that's pretty much what he's trying to do

Answer (score 1):

Create a "join table" :

```
CREATE TABLE user_loves_user (
    user_id1 int NOT NULL,
    user_id2 int NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE user_loves_user ADD PRIMARY KEY (user_id1, user_id2) ;
```

With your `user` table, it is enough to do what you want.